# Use adb (android debug bridge) in systemd-nspawn container

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb-device, container, systemd-nspawn, adb

I would like to use adb inside an systemd-nspawn container. Unfortunately I cannot access the phone inside the container (connected via USB).

```
pi@debian-buster-64:~ $ export ADB_TRACE=usb
pi@debian-buster-64:~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully

pi@debian-buster-64:~ $
```

Here is the container setup /etc/systemd/nspawn/debian-buster-64.nspawn:

```
[Exec]
PrivateUsers=no
Capability=CAP_NET_ADMIN

[Files]
Bind=/home
Bind=/run/user:/run/host-user/
BindReadOnly=/etc/resolv.conf

[Network]
Private=no
VirtualEthernet=no
```

Here is the output from lsusb from inside the container:

```
pi@debian-buster-64:~ $ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 045e:07b2 Microsoft Corp. 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0 used by mouse Wireless Desktop 900
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 18d1:4ee7 Google Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of lsusb is identical to the output on the host and the phone (Google Inc.) is visible.

I want to use adb inside the container because the container is 64bit (host is only 32bit). Unfortunately, adb on 32bit has limitations. Access with adb works on the host (with said 32bit limitations). Any ideas how to get this working inside the container?

Comment: `adb` talks directly to the `ADB Interface` function of the USB device. No mass storage or other driver is involved, so no need to pass through `/media`, `device-mapper` (that's not even related to USB in any way) or `sd`.  What exactly are you trying to achieve using the container? (As in, what degree of isolation do you need?) Can you see the device in `lsusb` inside the container? If yes, try `export ADB_TRACE=usb` before launching the adb daemon and see what you get.

Comment: Hi @TooTea, thank you for your reply! I have updated the questions with your input. I agree that the pass through of /media has nothing to do with this. It was in there so that I have access to my portable HDD inside the container. I have taken it out now because it might be confusing. Based on your input, I have also taken the rest out.